# Break array into individual elements and create new array by unique identifier

Tags: sql, presto

I have a array field that has 6 elements (the example here has 4 elements) and I would like to pivot this data and create a new array for each element.

This is likely a duplicate but I am not sure the appropriate title to pull up similar questions.

```
array<struct<Relative_Type:string,relative__name:relative_age:string,relative_id:string,relative_dept:string,title:string>>
```

---

Original  Table

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | Array                                                                          |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | [{"Relative Type":"Dad", "Relative Name":"Jerry", "Relative Age":"30"}]        |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | [{"Relative Type":"Mom", "Relative Name":"Beth", "Relative Age":"33"}]         |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | [{"Relative Type":"Sister", "Relative Name":"Summer", "Relative Age":"20"}]    |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | [{"Relative Type":"Grandfather", "Relative Name":"Rick", "Relative Age":"77"}] |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | [{"Relative Type":"Dad", "Relative Name":"Tom", "Relative Age":"43"}]          |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | [{"Relative Type":"Mom", "Relative Name":"Teresa", "Relative Age":"59"}]       |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Desired Table

```
+----+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| ID | Relative Type                   | Relative Name               | Relative Age     |
+----+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| 1  | (Dad, Mom, Sister, Grandfather) | (Jerry, Beth, Summer, Rick) | (30, 33, 20, 77) |
+----+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| 2  | (Dad, Mom)                      | (Tom, Teresa)               | (43, 59)         |
+----+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that you need to first [UNNEST](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/sql/select.html#unnest) and then [aggregate into an array](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg). See an example below:

```
> SELECT * FROM x;
 i |                                c
---+------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | [{relative_type=Sister, relative__name=Summer, relative_age=20}]
 1 | [{relative_type=Mom, relative__name=Betty, relative_age=33}]
 1 | [{relative_type=Dad, relative__name=Jerry, relative_age=30}]
 2 | [{relative_type=Mom, relative__name=Jane, relative_age=33}]
 2 | [{relative_type=Dad, relative__name=Tommy, relative_age=40}]
(5 rows)

> SELECT i, array_agg(relative_type), array_agg(relative__name), array_agg(relative_age) 
  FROM x, UNNEST (c) GROUP BY i;
 i |       _col1        |         _col2          |    _col3
---+--------------------+------------------------+--------------
 2 | [Dad, Mom]         | [Tommy, Jane]          | [40, 33]
 1 | [Mom, Sister, Dad] | [Betty, Summer, Jerry] | [33, 20, 30]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: How to I handle the quotes that I have?

Comment: This gives me the same query from your top query but removes the `[]` brackets. SO everything in between `{.....}` (+1 for assistance tho)